# Can one component receive data from two HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Within the Higher Order Component pattern, is there a way that a single presentational component can receive state from two HOC's?

For example:

```
const WithUserState = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      userData: { userId: 1252748, userName: 'thomas' }
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent userData={this.state.userData} />
    }
  }
}

const WithCommentState = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      userComments: [{id: 0, comment: 'hello'}, {id: 1, comment: 'world'}]
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent userComments={this.state.userComments} />
    }
  }
}

class UserAndComments extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <code>user: {JSON.stringify(this.props.userData)}</code>
        <hr />
        <code>comments: {JSON.stringify(this.props.userComments)}</code>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

I've heard it said this is possible, but my googling hasn't served me. The only thing I could think was maybe like to nest the function calls:

```
const ComonentWithUserAndComments = WithCommentState(WithUserState(UserAndComments))
```

This didn't work: I only receive the `userData` and `userComments` is empty.

#### Is it possible to get State data from two HOCs?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/309np71p2q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, update your `WithUserState` to pass props.

```js
const WithUserState = WrappedComponent => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      userData: { userId: 1252748, userName: 'thomas' }
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} userData={this.state.userData} />
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha. While this does work with what I have above, the nesting syntax (`WithCommentState(WithUserState(UserAndComments))`) is still awfully ugly. Is this the typical way to achieve this pattern? Or is there a smarter way?

Comment: IMO, this is probably the best way to do it short of using Redux (or a similar alternative).

Comment: Interesting. What is the redux way to do this?

Comment: You probably would also want to do the `{...this.props}` on your WithCommentState HOC too. Otherwise whatever props you pass to your HOC'd component won't make its way down.

Comment: Yeah, for sure.

Comment: I use recompose to compose HOCs: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose#composition

Comment: For redux, you would need to create a "reducer" for user and comments. Then you could use the `connect` HOC from the `react-redux` package to retrieve the user and comment state and pass it as props to your UserAndComments.

It would look something like
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({ user: state.user, comments: state.comments })`

then
`const MyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyOriginalComponent)`

Comment: If this answered your question don't forget to mark it! :D

Comment: yep, sorry about that!

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this and wants to do it in the future without the nested syntax, I made a function to reduce them, I find it a little cleaner: `const combineHocs = (Component, ...hocs) =>
  hocs.reduce((accumulatedHocs, hoc, index) => hoc(accumulatedHocs), Component)`